# Create KFold crossvalidation test and training sets with Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

Let's say I have a bunch of orders for each month. An order can also extend over certain months. I do some predictions and I want to validate my predictions with KFold crossvalidation. My goal is to create K test and training sets.

I group my order ids, separate the indexes into test an training sets and collect  rows based on those indexes.

The solution I came up with is slow because for every order id it uses `Series.filter` with `Seq.contains`. Does somebody know a more efficient way to do it in F#?

Simplified example:

```
#r "nuget: Deedle"
#r "nuget: FSharp.Stats"

open Deedle

type Order = 
  { OrderId:string; Month:int; Amount:int }

let OrderRecds = 
  [ { OrderId = "I1"; Month = 1; Amount = 100}
    { OrderId = "I2"; Month = 1; Amount = 200}
    { OrderId = "I3"; Month = 1; Amount = 300}
    { OrderId = "I4"; Month = 1; Amount = 400}
    { OrderId = "I5"; Month = 1; Amount = 500}
    { OrderId = "I6"; Month = 1; Amount = 600}
    { OrderId = "I1"; Month = 2; Amount = 100}
    { OrderId = "I2"; Month = 2; Amount = 200}
    { OrderId = "I3"; Month = 2; Amount = 300}
    { OrderId = "I4"; Month = 2; Amount = 400}
    { OrderId = "I5"; Month = 2; Amount = 500}
    { OrderId = "I6"; Month = 2; Amount = 600}
    { OrderId = "I1"; Month = 3; Amount = 100}
    { OrderId = "I2"; Month = 3; Amount = 200}
    { OrderId = "I3"; Month = 3; Amount = 300}
    { OrderId = "I4"; Month = 3; Amount = 400}
    { OrderId = "I5"; Month = 3; Amount = 500}
    { OrderId = "I6"; Month = 3; Amount = 600}
     ]

let df_order = OrderRecds |> Frame.ofRecords

let order_ids_series = 
    df_order 
    |> Frame.groupRowsByString "OrderId" 
    |> Frame.nest
    |> Series.indexOrdinally

let NUM_FOLDS = 3
let n = order_ids_series |> Series.countKeys
let chunkSize = int (ceil (float n / float NUM_FOLDS))
let chunkIndices =
        [|0 .. n-1|]
        |> FSharp.Stats.Array.shuffleFisherYates
        |> Seq.chunkBySize chunkSize

let train_indexes =
    { 0 .. NUM_FOLDS - 1 }
    |> Seq.map (fun i -> chunkIndices |> Seq.removeAt i |> Seq.concat)

let test_indexes = chunkIndices

let train_data = 
    train_indexes 
    |> Seq.map (fun indexes -> order_ids_series |> Series.filter (fun k _ -> Seq.contains k indexes) ) 
    |> Seq.map Frame.unnest 
    |> Seq.map (Frame.mapRowKeys snd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One concern I had with another answer was that `Frame.unnest` or `Frame.mergeAll` takes a lot of time. This solution creates a map of the indexes and uses `filterRows`. On my dataset it is roughly 60 times faster.

```ml
let df_order_grouped = 
    df_order 
    |> Frame.groupRowsByString "OrderId"

let order_ids_series = 
  df_order_grouped
    |> Frame.nest

let order_ids = order_ids_series.Keys

let NUM_FOLDS = 3
let n = order_ids_series |> Series.countKeys
let chunkSize = int (ceil (float n / float NUM_FOLDS))
let chunkIndices =
        order_ids |> Array.ofSeq
        |> FSharp.Stats.Array.shuffleFisherYates
        |> Seq.chunkBySize chunkSize

let train_indexes =
    { 0 .. NUM_FOLDS - 1 }
    |> Seq.map (fun i -> chunkIndices |> Seq.removeAt i |> Seq.concat)

let test_indexes = chunkIndices

let toMap (indexes:seq<string>)= 
    indexes 
    |> Seq.map (fun i -> i,true) 
    |> Map.ofSeq

let filter (indexes:Map<string,bool>) (df:Frame<string*int,string>) = 
    df 
    |> Frame.filterRows (fun k _ -> indexes.ContainsKey (fst k))

let train_data:seq<Frame<string*int,string>> =
    train_indexes
       |> Seq.map (fun indexes -> filter (indexes |> toMap) df_order_grouped)

train_data |> Seq.iter (fun df -> df.Print())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick is to access the series by its key, so you can go directly to the corresponding value. So try something like this instead:

```ml
let train_data =
    train_indexes
    |> Seq.map (fun indexes ->
         indexes
            |> Seq.sort
            |> Seq.map (fun index -> order_ids_series.[index])   // access the series by its key
            |> Series.ofValues)
    |> Seq.map Frame.unnest 
    |> Seq.map (Frame.mapRowKeys snd)
```

### Update #1

In order to improve performance, I think you can get rid of `Frame.unnest`, like this:

```ml
let train_data =
    train_indexes
    |> Seq.map (fun indexes ->
         indexes
            |> Seq.map (fun index -> order_ids_series.[index])
            |> Frame.mergeAll)
```

This doesn't seem to preserve the row order, but hopefully still works for you. Further optimizations along these lines may be possible.

### Update #2

I just benchmarked `unnest` vs. `mergeAll` performance on 24,000 rows and they both take about 9.6 seconds on my box. I'm not sure how to get that number down further. I do think the `mergeAll` version is simpler to understand, but it doesn't actually seem to be faster.

Comment: Of course, you are right! Thank you! But still, the full data set takes now about 6 minutes with this improvement whereas if do it with Python it is done in seconds.

Comment: How many records do you have in your data set? Have you tried compiling the code as an executable, instead of using F# interactive?

Comment: After looking at the code for a bit, I think that `Frame.unnest` is overkill. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again. Indeed, `mergeAll` doesn't seem to be quicker but I don't have to fiddle with the row keys. I have around 150,000 rows and 4,500 unique order ids. Compiled it takes about 5 minutes. Best solution so far.

Comment: One other thing that occurred to me is that you really don’t need Deedle for this at all. A solution using just the native F# `Seq` module might be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the base library is simpler and faster. This takes less than a tenth of a second on my laptop using a 162k sample size.

```ml
let kfold folds data =
    let rand = new System.Random()
    let splits =
        data 
        |> List.sortBy (fun _ -> rand.NextDouble())
        |> List.splitInto folds 
    [ for i = 0 to folds-1 do 
        splits |> List.removeAt i |> List.concat, 
        splits[i] ]
```

Showing an example for an integer list

```ml
kfold 3 [0..5]
// [([5; 2; 1; 0], [3; 4]); ([3; 4; 1; 0], [5; 2]); ([3; 4; 5; 2], [1; 0])]
```

Now on large sample of your data:

```ml
// 162k sample size
let orderRecds =
    [ for i = 1 to 4_500 do
      for j = 1 to 12  do
      for k = 1 to 3 do
        { OrderId = string i; Month = j; Amount = i * j  }]

let groupedOrderRecds = 
    orderRecds 
    |> List.groupBy (fun order -> order.OrderId)

let train_data = 
    kfold 3 groupedOrderRecds
    |> List.map (fun (train, test) ->
        train |> List.collect snd,
        test |> List.collect snd)

// first train and test sample
let train0, test0 = train_data[0]
```